# Шифрование файла почти "на лету"

Tags: linux, bash, шифрование

Задача: зашифровать файл, но чтобы в папке остался только зашифрованный файл.

Нашел решение типа такого

```
#!/bin/bash

# Генерирую ключи открытый и закрытый
openssl genrsa -out private.pem -aes256 2048
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -out public.pem

# Generate the random symmetric-key
PASSIZE=30
if [ -c /dev/urandom ] ; then
KEY=`head -c 30 /dev/urandom | openssl enc -base64`
else
KEY=`openssl rand -base64 30`
fi
export KEY

# Encrypt the symmetric key using the public key
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey "$PUBLICKEY" -out "$SESSIONKEY" -pubin <<EOF
$KEY
EOF

# Зашифровываю файл
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pass env:KEY -in "$FILENAME" -out "$RESULT"

# Затираю оригинал файла, предварительно заменив его содержимое
pwgen > $FILENAME  # Много раз
echo -n > $FILENAME
rm -rf $FILENAME
```

В папке остается сам зашифрованный файл.

Вопросы:

- Восстановление файла с помощью r-studio/testdisk'a даст результат исходного файла, или данные затерлись/побились? (проверить пока не могу, иначе бы не спрашивал)
- Чем/как можно увеличить скорость шифрования? Большие файлы по 300Мб и больше долго шифруются... ну как долго, ожидаемо долго конечно, все-таки большой файл. Может быть, есть более быстрый способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Восстановление файла с помощью r-studio/testdisk'a даст результат исходного файла или данные затерлись/побились?

после `pwgen > $FILENAME`? насколько я понимаю, будет затёрто лишь девять первых байт файла. и то, если запись будет производиться в тот же самый inode.

для затирания содержимого файла всё же лучше использовать предназначенные для этого программы.

например, входящую в [*gnu/coreutils*](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) (присутствует по умолчанию во всех дистрибутивах операционной системы *gnu*) программу [*gnu/shred*](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shred-invocation.html). файл сначала будет перезаписан (по умолчанию — трижды, можно задать количество с помощью опции `-n`) а затем удалён (опция `-u`):

```
$ shred -u /путь/к/файлу
```

---

**дополнение от [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)**

для надежности, на файловых системах *ext3/ext4* можно поставить перед удалением флаг 'безопасного удаления' `chattr +s filename`. Правда, говорят, не во всех ядрах этот флаг даст результат. так что именно как дополнение.

Comment: после pwgen > $FILENAME получаю файл размером в 4Кб... тоже думал. что он только часть заменит, при восстановлении..

Answer (score 2):

Есть encfs. Делает то что надо и правильно.

OpenSSL еще поддерживает аппаратное шифрование (если оно есть в процессоре)

```
openssl speed aes-256-cbc

openssl speed  -evp aes-256-cbc
```

Последняя в 4 раза быстрее на моем FX-6300

Comment: Ругается на openssl speed  -evp aes-256-cbc грит нет таких ключей как speed и -evp

Comment: Наверное у вас устаревшая версия (evp появился вроде с 1,0) или так собран. У меня openssl 1.0.1f

Comment: openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015

Comment: А процессор вообще такое умеет?
grep "aes" cat /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: Выдал aes - этот греп